# set table view in View controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

Here's my problem. I created a view controller and I inserted a table view(with a cell) in it. I have also a text field at the bottom of the view controller. The aim is to put in the cell the text I wrote in the text field. I tried a lot of things but no results.
Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code ( I can't display the NSLog)

```
My .h
@interface RBChatViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *entryTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

My .m
#import "RBChatViewController.h"

@interface RBChatViewController ()

@end

@implementation RBChatViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.entryTextField.delegate=self;
 self.tableview.delegate=self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
   NSLog(@" numberofsections");
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to post what you have tried and explain what issue you are having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell you what is happening without seeing your code but this code should work.

```
-(void)addTextToTable {
    //method runs when you push a button to say i am done writing in text field

    NSString *textFeildText = self.textFeild.text;  //create string of textfeild text
    [self.mutableArray addObject:textFeildText];  //add string to dataSource array
    [self.table reloadData];  // update table with new data to show the new string that is created
}
```

EDIT Here is what you need to add.

```
       My .h
    @interface RBChatViewController :                          UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>


    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *entryTextField;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mutArray;  // array of object that will be in the tableview

     My .m
    #import "RBChatViewController.h"

    @interface RBChatViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation RBChatViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.entryTextField.delegate=self;
     self.tableview.delegate=self;
     self.tableview.dataDelegate = self;  // ADD THIS, this means that the data for the          tableview is gather from here  This will also display your NSLog
    _mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //create your mutable array
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
       NSLog(@" numberofsections");
       return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        //tells how many rows in your tableview based on object in array
        return _mutArray.count;

    }




    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       NSString *string = [_mutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = string;


     return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Yes I forgot the self.tableview.datasource = self;

Answer (score 0):

You should have `tableView` and textField property then, 
You must implment the `delegate` and `datasource` methods of `tableView`. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the `cell.titleLabel.text = self.textField.text`, And call `[tableView reloadata];` from `textFieldDidChangeText`, or if you have some button add reload code in that button action.